# How to update a date field to "Today" date

Tags: process-builder

I'm trying to update a Start date based on a Status change to "In Progress".

I have the process builder meeting this criteria when the status changes to In Progress.

Below is the formula, I'm trying to default the `Start_Date__c` to today's date (the day they change the status)

```
[Engagement__c]Start_Date__c = (DATEVALUE(TODAY() )
```

Comment: You don't need to use `DateValue()`, `Today()` return only date part by default. DateValue() function take date text format..

Answer (score 5):

[image]1. If you want to use today then use the formula TODAY
2. If you want to use CreatedDate the use DATEVALUE([Account].CreatedDate)

Comment: how do you default today's date but not override the date each time the record is saved